# VBA For loop not exiting

Tags: vba, excel

I am looping through rows of a table and deleting rows if certain conditions are not met. For some reason my for loop never exits even when its done. What am I doing wrong?

```
lastr = Range("a2").End(xlDown).Row
For r = 2 To lastr
    If Cells(r, 1).Value <> "SHORT POSITIONS" And Cells(r, 7).Value = 0 And Cells(r, 10).Value <> "Yes" Then
        Rows(r).Delete
        r = r - 1
        lastr = lastr - 1
    End If
Next r
```

Comment: What's the value of lastr if you put a breakpoint a the For line?

Comment: Usually, when deleting rows if a for loop, it is easier to do i starting by the end: `For r = lastr to 2 step -1`. This way, you don't have to bother with `r = r-1` and `lastr = lastr -1`

Comment: How do I check what the value of lastr is ? I set the breakpoint

Comment: There is multiple ways. You can mouse over the name, look in the Local variables windows, set a spy, type `? lastr`in the immediate window...

Comment: Its 123 which is correct

Comment: In a For... loop, the end value is saved when the For code is evaluated. If you run the code step by step, you will see that when reaching the Next, who go back to the line following the For, not the for itself. So you can't modify the end value inside the loop., the loop will run 123 times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ALWAYS start at the bottom and work towards the top when deleting rows. Failing to work from the bottom to the top will result in skipped rows as the position of the rows are reset after the row deletion.

NEVER reset your counter in a [For ... Next Statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ebk1751.aspx). Changing `r` mucks things up. Changing `lastr` has no effect. It will still go to the `lastr` that was the original value when you entered the loop.

```
lastr = Range("a" & ROWS.COUNT).End(xlUP).Row
For r = lastr To 2 STEP -1   '<~~ VERY IMPORTANT
    If Cells(r, 1).Value <> "SHORT POSITIONS" And Cells(r, 7).Value = 0 And Cells(r, 10).Value <> "Yes" Then
        Rows(r).Delete
    End If
Next r
```

TYPICALLY, it is better to look for the last populated cell from the bottom up,

Answer (score 0):

if you want to loop and delete its best to mark the rows first and delete them at once or use an array.

```
lastr = Range("a2").End(xlDown).Row
dim DR() as long
dim c as long
For r = 2 To lastr
    If Cells(r, 1).Value <> "SHORT POSITIONS" And Cells(r, 7).Value = 0 And Cells(r, 10).Value <> "Yes" Then
        c = c +1
        redim preserve DR(c)
        dr(c-1) = R
    End If
Next r
'delete the rows one by one, or you could build a string and delete once.
For r = 0 to UBound(DR)
    Rows(dr(i).delete ' or entirerow delete 
next i
```

Answer (score 0):

You are subtracting 1 from the loop variable, so it loops forever.

In Visual Basic for loops, "from" and "to" are calculated once at the beginning (they are fixed), but the loop variable is increased each time. So

```
For r = fromExp to toExp
  SomeCode()
End For
```

behaves the same as

```
    Dim f = fromExp
    Dim t = toExp

    r = f

    While (r < t)
       SomeCode()
       r = r + 1
    End While
```

In your example, the code changes toExp

```
For r = fromExp to toExp
   toExp = toExp + 1
   r = r - 1
EndFor
```

but that *doesn't affect the loop*:

```
    Dim f = fromExp
    Dim t = toExp

    r = f

    While (r < t)
       toExp = toExp + 1   // does not affect the loop
       r = r - 1
       r = r + 1           // r is unchanged
    End While
```

The loop variable is unchanged, so it loops forever.

Best practice: **do not** alter the loop variable within a For loop.